# logstash and centralised redis problems

Tags: redis, logstash

I'm trying to get logstash working in a centralised setup using the docs as an example:

http://logstash.net/docs/1.2.2/tutorials/getting-started-centralized

I've got logstash (as indexer), redis, elasticsearch and standalone kibana3 running on my web server. I then need to run logstash as an agent on another server to collect apache logs and send them to the web server via redis. The number of agents will increase and the logs will vary, but for now I just want to get this working!

I need everything to run as a service so that all is well after reboots etc. All servers are running Ubuntu.

For all logstash instances (indexer and agent), I'm using the following init script (Ubuntu version, second gist):

https://gist.github.com/shadabahmed/5486949#file-logstash-ubuntu

For running redis as a service, I followed the instructions here:

http://redis.io/topics/quickstart (Installing redis more properly)

Elasticsearch is also running as a service.

On the web server, running `redis-cli` returns `PONG` correctly. Navigating to the correct Elasticsearch URL returns the correct JSON response. Navigating to the Kibana3 url gives me the dashboard, but no data. UFW is set to allow the redis port (at the moment from everywhere).

On the web server, my logstash.conf is:

```
input {
    file {
      path => "/var/log/apache2/access.log"
      type => "apache-access"
      sincedb_path => "/etc/logstash/.sincedb"
    }
    redis {
      host => "127.0.0.1"
      data_type => "list"
      key => "logstash"
      codec => json
    }
}

filter {
  grok {
    type => "apache-access"
    pattern => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}"
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    embedded => true
  }
  statsd {
    # Count one hit every event by response
    increment => "apache.response.%{response}"
  }
}
```

From the agent server, I can telnet successfully to the web server IP and redis port. logstash is running. The logstash.conf file is:

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/var/log/apache2/shift.access.log"
    type => "apache"
    sincedb_path => "/etc/logstash/since_db"
  }
  stdin {
     type => "example"
   }
}

filter {
  if [type] == "apache" {
    grok {
      pattern => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}"
    }
  }
}

output {
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
  redis { host => ["xx.xx.xx.xx"] data_type => "list" key => "logstash" }
}
```

If I comment out the `stdin` and `stdout` lines, I still don't get a result. The logstash logs do not give me any connection errors - only warnings about the deprecated `grok` settings format.

I have also tried running logstash from the command line (making sure to stop the demonised service first). The apache log file is correctly outputted in the terminal, so I know that logstash is accessing the log correctly. And I can write random strings and they are output in the correct logstash format.

The redis logs on the web server show no sign of trouble......

The frustrating thing is that this has worked once. One message from `stdin` made it all the way through to elastic search. That was this morning just after getting everything setup. Since then, I have had no luck and I have no idea why!

Any tips/pointers gratefully received... Solving my problem will stop me tearing out more of my hair which will also make my wife happy......

### UPDATE

Rather than filling the comments....

Thanks to @Vor and @rutter, I've confirmed that the user running logstash can read/write to the logstash.log file.

I've run the agent with -vv and the logs are populated with e.g.:

```
{:timestamp=>"2013-12-12T06:27:59.754000+0100", :message=>"config LogStash::Outputs::Redis/@host = [\"XX.XX.XX.XX\"]", :level=>:debug, :file=>"/opt/logstash/logstash.jar!/logstash/config/mixin.rb", :line=>"104"}
```

I then input random text into the terminal and get stdout results. However, I do not see anything in the logs until AFTER terminating the logstash agent. After the agent is terminated, I get lines like these in the logstash.log:

```
{:timestamp=>"2013-12-12T06:27:59.835000+0100", :message=>"Pipeline started", :level=>:info, :file=>"/opt/logstash/logstash.jar!/logstash/pipeline.rb", :line=>"69"}

{:timestamp=>"2013-12-12T06:29:22.429000+0100", :message=>"output received", :event=>#<LogStash::Event:0x77962b4d @cancelled=false, @data={"message"=>"test", "@timestamp"=>"2013-12-12T05:29:22.420Z", "@version"=>"1", "type"=>"example", "host"=>"Ubuntu-1204-precise-64-minimal"}>, :level=>:info, :file=>"(eval)", :line=>"16"}

{:timestamp=>"2013-12-12T06:29:22.461000+0100", :level=>:debug, :host=>"XX.XX.XX.XX", :port=>6379, :timeout=>5, :db=>0, :file=>"/opt/logstash/logstash.jar!/logstash/outputs/redis.rb", :line=>"230"}
```

But while I do get messages in stdout, I get nothing in redis on the other server. I can however telnet to the correct port on the other server, and I get "ping/PONG" in telnet, so redis on the other server is working..... And there are no errors etc in the redis logs.

It looks to me very much like the redis plugin on the logstash shipper agent is not working as expected, but for the life of me, I can't see where the breakdown is coming from.....

Comment: You're sure Kibana isn't showing any errors? Have you tried using `curl` to submit searches directly? Something like `curl -XGET http://your.es.host:9200/logstash-2013.12.10/_search:type=apache`. You might try running your Logstash agents manually with `-v` to watch each plugin handling your data.

Comment: I know `patterns` is depricated, but have you tried using `match` instead?

Comment: Thanks @rutter - I've tried querying ES directly and there's only one result which is the single test message which went through first time around. I've tried running the Logstash agents manually with -vv and nothing hits the logs at all, other than blue config messages.

Comment: Thanks @Vor - I'll try that now, but I'm pretty sure the problem is before that stage, especially since patterns is deprecated, not removed.

Comment: @Vor - still no joy. I think my best bet at this stage may be to uninstall everything and start again....

Comment: Jus a one question, do you have permissions to write to /etc/logstash?

Comment: @Vor - a good point. What user does logstash run under if it's running as a service? I have set 775 temporarily on the logstash-specific logs though.....

Comment: you can check it yourself by doing `ps aux | grep logstash`

Comment: If you're running with `-vv` and *nothing* is hitting the logs, then your inputs aren't receiving data. Could be it's thinking the file is already read. You might try deleting your sincedb and running the file input with [`start_position` set to "beginning"](http://logstash.net/docs/1.2.2/inputs/file#start_position).